# Organisation postes blog

Tags: html, css

when i create page blog, i have the poste with  deferent size, i find this

[image]

but i want this

[image]

This is my code:

```css
.col{
 width: 500px;
 margin: 0 1.5% 10px 1.5%;
 border: solid thin #363636;
 float: left;
}

.col-1{height: 100px;}
.col-2{height: 50px;}
.col-3{height: 340px;}
.col-4{height: 260px;}
.col-5{height: 280px;}
.col-6{height: 300px;}
.col-7{height: 220px;}
.col-8{height: 240px;}
```

```html
<div class="col col-1">Article 1</div>
<div class="col col-2">Article 2</div>
<div class="col col-3">Article 3</div>
<div class="col col-4">Article 4</div>
<div class="col col-1">Article 5</div>
<div class="col col-2">Article 6</div>
<div class="col col-3">Article 7</div>
<div class="col col-4">Article 8</div>
```

**P.S: i have too many post in my blog not just 4**

Thanks for your help

Comment: That code that you have written looks so confusing to me? You are using bootstrap?

Comment: Just check the flexbox layout answer on the question that is marked as duplicate if you don't want to use any jquery module.

Comment: Do you give me the code solution !

Comment: Check the flexbox layout answer on that post, you'll get your answer.

Comment: it's not working -_-, do you give me the code working !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118800/discussion-between-hassan-saghir-and-gandalf-the-white).